# leg_detector and kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, leg-detector, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am trying to run a leg_detector2 package from here:

http://code.google.com/p/wu-robotics/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fpeople2

Has anyone had success to run it with kinect? I think that it should not be the problem. I successfully remapped kinect's laser scan to base_scan. But now I don't now how to read or visualize detected legs or any data produced by leg_detector.

I would really appreciate if anybody has any tips.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31366/leg_detector-and-kinect/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2012-04-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I successfully run it with some minor adjustments.
First you have to edit your launch file and add to start openni, pointcloud_to_laser_scan and remap kinects laser scan from scan to base_scan.
To properly show the data in rviz I modified all .cpp and .py files to change fixed_frame from odom_combined to camera_depth_frame. Maybe you won't have to do that if you actually use odom_combined.
In the end don't forget to rosmake it.
Now you should be able to show leg detection in rviz by adding MARKER.

---

Originally posted by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) with karma: 460 on 2012-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Grega

I just ported the leg_detector2 package to work with Hydro and the Kinect:

https://github.com/jdddog/people

Thanks

Jamie

---

Originally posted by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) with karma: 123 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-28**:
It sounds good! I will try it. Thanks, @James Diprose

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-29**:
I have an ERROR at compiling the package.

```
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['leg_detector']                                      
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

**Comment by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) on 2014-05-02**:
No worries, did you clone the entire directory?

e.g. git clone https://github.com/jdddog/people.git

And make the stack (not just one package):

rosmake people

It also needs to be in your rosbuild workspace because I haven't had time to port it to catkin.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-05-02**:
Thanks, @James Diprose If following you, compiling  succeeded.

**Comment by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) on 2014-05-09**:
You're welcome Ken!